# count patterns in a csv file from another csv file in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have two csv files

File A

```
ID
1
2
3
```

File B

```
ID
1
1
1
1
3
2
3
```

What I want to do is to count how many times that a ID in File A show up in File B, and save the result in a new file C (which is in csv format). For example, 1 in File A shows up 4 times in File B. So in the new file C, I should have something like

```
File C
ID,Count
1,4
2,1
3,2
```

Originally I was thinking use "grep -f", but it seems like it only works with .txt format. Unfortunately, File A and B are both in csv format. So now, I am thinking maybe I could use a for loop to get the ID from File A individually and use grep -c to count each one of them. Any idea will be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -v OFS=, 'FNR==1{next} FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a{freq[$1]++}
              END{print "ID", "Count"; for (i in freq) print i, freq[i]}' fileA fileB

ID,Count
1,4
2,1
3,2
```

Comment: excellent answer! and it did the work. But just wondering what does  $1 in a{freq[$1]++} do? particularly, what is a? is that a list or something?

Comment: `a` is an associate array that is populated with `id` from `fileA`. Then `$1 in a` checks if `$1` from `fileB` exists in array `a`. If it does exist then populate and increment another array `freq`

Comment: so they are just self-defined array. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `join`, `sort`, `uniq` and *process substitution* `<(command)` creatively:

```
$ join -2 2 <(sort A) <(sort B | uniq -c) | sort -n > C
$ cat C
ID 1
1 4
2 1
3 2
```

And if you really really want the header to be `ID Count`, before writing to file `C` you could replace that `1` with `Count` with `sed` by adding:

```
... | sed 's/\(ID \)1/\1Count/' > C
```

to get

```
ID Count
1 4
2 1
3 2
```

and if you really really want commas as separators instead of spaces, to replace them with spaces using `tr`, add also:

```
... | tr \  , > C
```

to get

```
ID,Count
1,4
2,1
3,2
```

You could of course ditch the `tr`and use the `sed` like this instead:

```
... | sed 's/\(ID \)1/\1Count/;s/ /,/' > C
```

And the output would be like above.